# LibreOffice Calc copy/paste to Google Spreadsheets skips empty rows

Tags: linux, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets, xlsx

The problem is in that, that when I copy selection range from LibreOffice Calc to Google Spreadsheet, the result are copied with empty rows missing. The row in the selection must have all cells empty to skip.

This behaviour did me some trouble, as the pasted data got shifted up the number rows skipped. My eye didn't catch the fact and I have got some troubles at work.

I have LibreOffice version 6. Source file is in `Microsoft XLSX` format.

Could someone point me how to turn this feature off? Maybe it is a Google thing? Any advice will be appriciated.

***update***

Today I noticed that the copy/paste not only skips empty rows but also does skip empty columns! It is such a pain to manage.

Thanks

Comment: A dummy column with non-empty content should circumvent the issue. In the target sheet you just ignore/delete it. Cumbersome, I know. I hope you'll find a real solution.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I do a copy/paste from pivot table. Sometimes I use `sum` as aggregate function, sometime I use `count`. In case of `sum` I can get data with nulls, so the pivot table can tune to show zeroes(hopefully). I don`t know what to do in case of `count`.